# Isn't Inline Array Annotation DI compatible with $routeProvider in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, coffeescript

My codes looks like this

```
angular
.module('main', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider',
    ($routeProvider) ->
    $routeProvider
    .when '/',
      templateUrl: 'homePage/homePage.html'
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
])

angular.module('main').controller('MainCtrl',
 ['$scope' , ($scope) ->
    $scope.test = {}])
```

The browser will compain `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got Object`.

But if I don't use the inline array dependency injection in `MainCtrl` and rewrite it like this:

```
angular.module('main').controller('MainCtrl',
 ($scope) ->
    $scope.test = {})
```

Then everything works well. Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message is very clear on the fact that issue is not with `$routeProvider`, You may want to restructure them. Also note that config block must have a function.

First create the module, then register the controller and config:

```
angular
.module('main', ['ngRoute']);
```

and then use it or chain through, i.e

```
angular.module("main", ["ngRoute"]).controller("MainCtrl", [
  "$scope"
  ($scope) ->
    return $scope.test = {}
]).config [
  "$routeProvider"
  ($routeProvider) -> //Check this
    return $routeProvider.when("/",
      templateUrl: "homePage/homePage.html"
      controller: "MainCtrl"
    )
]
```

otherwise with the order of the script you have you are trying to create a controller on the app `main` before even it exists.

Also note that you need to include angular-router script as well.

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/H37QSQ?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks, the error is that I place the right bracket in the wrong place (wrap another controller in the callback).. which can not be found in my test code above..

Comment: Yeah i do not use coffeescript, i had to use coffee2js to see that . :)